# what's the summation of this finite sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series, closed-form

$a$ and $b$ are positive integers.
The summation is 
$$\sum\limits_{x = 1}^a {x\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{a + b - x}\\
b
\end{array}} \right)} .$$
Any closed-form expression?

I thought it should have. And maybe there is some physical meaning behind it.

---

Sorry, I've simplified the problem, and now it becomes easier.

Comment: What do you mean by "physical meaning"?

Comment: Some intuition behind the solution. How to understand it intuitively.:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the binomial identity $\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{m}{j}\binom{n-m}{k-j} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$ with $j = 1$, $n = a+ b$ and $k = b+1$.

Comment: It makes sense! You are so smart! Could you give some physical ideas behind this equation? Many THANKS!

Comment: Think of the ways of choosing $k+1$ objects out of $n+1$. In one way of counting it is simply $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$, and in another you fix $j$, and count the ways to choose the objects so that the $m+1$st object is the $j+1$st chosen.

Comment: It makes sense. Do you know the name of the formula?

Comment: I've decided to give you the bounty. But the system notifies me that I cannot operate until 24 hours later. You are the first, I will operate it tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not sure it has a name. It is identity #8 on the Wikipedia page for binomial coefficients.

Comment: If time is possible, hope you can make your answer more detailed (for example, share some ideas to understand the equation, and give the final result) to do good to future people that are interested in this problem.:-)

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha produces:$$\sum_{x=1}^a x \binom{a+b-x}{b} =\frac{(a+b) (a+b+1) \binom{a+b-1}{b}}{(b+1) (b+2)}$$
Full simplification of RHS: $$\frac{\Gamma (a+b+2)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (b+3)}$$

Comment: Cool! Could you give some analytical ideas?

Comment: @Fred: Mine didn't include the $x$... * embarrassed noises *. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Some experimentation gives $\dbinom{a+b+1}{b+2}$. This is the correct answer for $1\le a, b\le 5$.